# Combining two columns of a table and returning it as a single column separated by 'slash' if both the values are NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am working on a SQL view which extracts data from a table with multiple columns in it and returns single column with data combined form two columns for a table  separated by a slash , but I want the view to return the data such that whenever one of the two column values is null then it should return the value which is not `NULL` without any slash in it and if both the values are `NULL` then it should be empty or `NULL`

For Example, 
I am creating a view which returns two columns named `Give` and `Quantity` from a table in which there are four records for `ID(0,1,2,3)`,  `Give (NULL, 90, NULL, 60)` and `Quantity` column as `NULL, 110, 99, 100.` I have been able to create a view which return these values in the following order

Give/Quantity
        /
      90/110
       /99
      60/100

But I want the view which returns something like following

```
 Give/Quantity
     Empty
    90/110
      99
    60/100
```

As we can see from above that if either `Give` or `Quantity` is `NULL` then it should discard slash / and return the value that is `NOT NULL`

May I know a better way to achieve this.

I have the following query for the view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Result]
AS

with CTE as(
SELECT distinct
    CC.Term   
   iCC.Give,
   iCC.Volume


   FROM Cust CC
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 3
                Give,
                Quantity, 
               ISNULL(cast(iCC.Give as varchar(99)),'') + '/' + ISNULL(cast(iCC.Qunatity as varchar(99)),'') as Give/Quantity,
             FROM Cust iCC
             WHERE CC.Term = iCC.Term 
             ORDER BY iCC.Give DESC) iCC)
             select  Term, Give, givelabel as label from CTE 
             union
             select Product, Term, Quantity, quantitylabel from CTE 

GO
```

Comment: For me it looks like just CASE WHEN

Comment: Try the COALESCE function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
Id,
CASE 
WHEN Give IS NOT NULL and Quanity IS NOT NULL THEN Give + '/' + Quanity
WHEN Give IS NOT NULL and Quanity IS NULL THEN Give
WHEN Give IS NULL and Quanity IS NOT NULL THEN Quanity
WHEN Give IS NULL and Quanity IS NULL THEN NULL
END as 'Give/Quanity'
from
View
```

If Give or/and Quanity is other type than varchar you might need to convert them to varchar so query looks like:

```
SELECT
Id,
CASE 
WHEN Give IS NOT NULL and Quanity IS NOT NULL THEN convert(varchar(50),Give) + '/' + convert(varchar(50),Quanity)
WHEN Give IS NOT NULL and Quanity IS NULL THEN Give
WHEN Give IS NULL and Quanity IS NOT NULL THEN Quanity
WHEN Give IS NULL and Quanity IS NULL THEN NULL
END as 'Give/Quanity'
from
Table
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simple solution using `COALESCE`:

```
create table #t(Give int, Quantity int)
insert #t values
(null, null),
(90, 110),
(null, 99),
(60, 100),
(23, null)

select coalesce(cast(give as varchar)+'/'+cast(quantity as varchar),cast(give as varchar),cast(quantity as varchar))
from #t
```